# XML::Twig Use twig handlers or twig roots to update part of xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have been using the module XML::Twig in Perl for a few weeks now. So far I have been loading an entire xml file into memory and then editing values in the file. Finally I save the file under a new name for further use.

Up until now I have been dealing with fairly small xml files but now have to do some modifications on some very large xml files (10 000+ lines).

There are 100's of tags in these large files but I only want to modify, let's say, 10 of them.

Is there a way to load in just the tags I need to modify. Change the tag values and then save the resulting changes to a new xml file that has all the information the original one had but has the 10 tags modified?

see in the XML::Twig documentation that there are twig handlers to load in just part of an xml document, however in the examples I have tried when trying to modify just a few tags only those modified parts are returned as an xml file and the rest of the information is lost! Which is no good to me.

Below is an example structure I am dealing with

```
<datatag1 a="1A">
    <t>A</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="B2">
    <t>D</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="3C">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="4S3">
    <t>14</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="5AA3">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
```

What I would like to do is change datatag1's child t value, let's say, from A to B where a="1A". So then my modified xml would be:

```
<datatag1 a="1A">
    <t>B</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="B2">
    <t>D</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="3C">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="4S3">
    <t>14</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="5AA3">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
```

Furthermore, I have a hash containing a set of keys that list the "a" values I want to modify. The hashes values giving the new "t" values I want to insert.

Please let me know if you require any further information or anything is unclear.

Comment: If you want to write out the whole structure you have to load it in, there is no way around that. If your files are too big (100s of tags is not a good measure, lines or bytes are), you can do [chunked processing](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#Processing-an-XML-document-chunk-by-chunk).

Comment: You forgot to [flush](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig#flush-($optional_filehandle,-%options)).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you absolutely can do this with `XML::Twig`.

The core point is that a `twig_handler` fires as the parse is happening. However, to output the 'story so far' you need to `flush` - or maybe `purge`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

sub modify_datatag {
    my ( $twig, $datatag ) = @_;

    if ( $datatag -> att('a') eq '1A' ) {
        $datatag -> first_child('t') -> set_text('new text here'); 

    }

    #delete this, as it breaks the XML. But you get the point. 
    print "\n## flushing twig from memory\n";
    $twig -> flush;

}

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new ( 'twig_handlers' => { 'datatag1' => \&modify_datatag } ); 
$xml -> parse ( \*DATA );
$xml -> flush;


__DATA__
<xml>
<datatag1 a="1A">
    <t>B</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="B2">
    <t>D</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="3C">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="4S3">
    <t>14</t>
</datatag1>
<datatag1 a="5AA3">
    <t>1</t>
</datatag1>
</xml>
```

Each time the `flush` is called, the progress so far is output to the file. Any tags that are still being processed (e.g. aren't closed) will be retained in memory.

You could `purge` instead, but that will discard.

The above prints to `STDOUT` - but you can use `parsefile_inplace` to rewrite the existing file.

You can also specify a filehandle argument to `flush` to ... do what it says on the tin.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, I will test and let you know...One follow up question: Can I modify the handler to also insert new tags or is this not possible?

Comment: Yes, it can. Just bear in mind that when 'flush' is called, the state so far is dumped, and released from memory.  You can easily add a "child" of your current node. You can also insert as previous/next sibling if you want... but you can't really backtrack (because you `flush`ed already) or read ahead (because the parser hasn't "seen" later nodes yet).